# parsing html using pcre in python re module

Tags: python, pcre

i want to parsing below example in html

example is part of specific html.

```
<p>NUCLEAR EK:</p>

<ul>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:12 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /AgJVAhoAGFpMUAVU.html</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:13 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /AU4STwAHU1NMUUlcSlMHVAFRVwJTB1RKVx1XA1ZMAVUFSgRWTwBfVg</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:15 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoGGDpaIEUi</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:17 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoGGBpgEF8mYRhdIk9W</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:21 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoEGDpaIEUi</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:22 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoEGBpgEF8mYRhdIk9W</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:23 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /AU4STwAHU1NMUUlcSlMHVAFRVwJTB1RKVx1XA1ZMAVUFSgRWTxVaCBRVEA</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:25 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoLGDpaIEUi</li>
<li>2015-01-29 17:22:28 UTC - culturemerge.ga - GET /Al8OVhpVUFUBHgYYDh4CUgFWVwVQBFYGHgZIAlRQHlMCVBhQBxoLGBpgEF8mYRhdIk9W</li>
</ul>
```

i want to get content `<p>~</ul>`

so i make pcre python code below:

```
temp=re.findall(r"<p>[^\"\&\;]*?<\/p>\s*<ul>\s*<li>\d(.|\s)*?<\/ul>",html)
        print temp
```

this pcre is work well in notepad++ or Regex Coach

but in python it do not work parsing!

it show only empty list like `[]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: no... my goal is to find specific contents like example and to find name between <p> and </p>. so i find all contents like example. my pcre work well in Regex Coach. But do not work in python re

Comment: This question may already have an answer here: must be cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    temp=re.finditer(r"<p>[^\"\&\;]*?<\/p>\s*<ul>\s*<li>\d(.|\s)*?<\/ul>",html)
    for match in temp:
        print match.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree you shouldn't use regexp to parse html, sometimes it's ok. In this case I see some sort of a pattern, but I'm not quite sure about what you want to extract from the html. I'll just rewrite your regexp hoping it's what you're looking for:

```
temp=re.findall(r"<li>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} {\d:]{8}).* - (.*) - GET (.*)<\/li>",html)
for i in temp:
    print i
```

temp will contain tuples with this data (date, domain, path)